# Margins and % width and height

Tags: html, css

How can i add my margins and paddings to my height and width without changing the %

example:

```
height: 100%;
width : 100%;
margin-left:10px;
```

how can the margin be included in the calculation of width and height?

border-box?

Comment: you can use `box-sizing`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: border-box does not include maargins

Comment: Note that, margin is okay without box-sizing, but if you need to use `padding`, you need to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416651/including-margin-for-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use margin or paddings without some width or height, you must have some content inside your tag. If you can't change css just give some min-height/min-width in px or give a content. Here is an [example][1]

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/ostinred/pen/jPQBRW
```

Answer (score 0):

You may include padding and borders in the width/height but not margins. Margins are the area outside the element and thus the element can not claim the ownership of margins.