# Include padding/margin in width percentage?

Tags: html, css

How can I have `width:50%` with `panel-default`, but including `padding` or `margin` (not sure which one is more appropriate) in the calculation, so that the `panel-default` perfectly fills 100% of the width?

[image: SS]

**Code**

```css
.testing-here {
  padding: 2.5px;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-default {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  border-radius: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.panel-body {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="testing-here">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Right now if I set the `width` to `50%` all the panels dropdown vertically because they can't fit side by side.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including margin for width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416651/including-margin-for-width-and-height)

Comment: Google "include padding margin in width".

Comment: I did @torazaburo. Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to :

- add `box-sizing:border-box` to the `*,*:before,*:after`
- fix `inline-block` gap , you can do that by reset parents font, `font-size:0`
- remove  `display:inline` from `.testing-here`
- add `border` to `.panel-default`

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.testing-here {
  padding: 2.5px;
  font-size: 0
}
.panel-default {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 5px white solid
}
.panel-body {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="testing-here">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had updated question. I added `font-size: 0` to both parent div from your answer, but problem persists where panels are dropping down into vertical column

Comment: Thanks for still trying. Problem persists tho :/

Comment: Oh true. Idk what it can be then if I have your exact code.

Comment: Figured it out :) I had `testing-here` over each panel. You put it over all the panels. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the element

Comment: ... or the entire document. It helps maintain sanity.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes! But when I put that in `body { }` and then make `width: 50%` the panels don't fit in the row anymore and turns into one column.

Comment: I didn't do that, but you know why my problem is persisting? I updated question with new code

Comment: obviously what you posted isn't your complete code, so it's hard to tell