# Stretch div to full width inside fixed width element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a blog page, I am using `col-md-8`, Inside `col-md-8` my content exists, But I wanna stretch one of my div to be stretch to full width which is in `col-md-8`. My page

[image]

I wanna make it stretch,
My code:

```css
.joinUs {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -33.333333%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="article--publishedDate smallText text-uppercase">
          Published : 02 June 2019
        </div>
        <div class="article--topDescription mt-54px">
          In the above video, I have talked about top font management apps for Windows and Mac OS. Most of the Windows Font Management apps are Free and for Mac most of them are paid. I have talked about the top apps for Windows and Mac.
        </div>

        // I wanna make it stretch to full width of the browser
        <div class="joinUs">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="sectionTitle allCaps-Bold">
                <span>Start learning for FREE Today - Visual Design Class</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="joinUs--title">
                Join my community of <span>41257</span> students from <span>170</span> countries worldwide.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But it doesn't work

[image]

Please help me, I am stuck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS 100% height with padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 what does 100% height have to do with strech div width?

Comment: no bro, It's not. Please read my question

Comment: Also check screenshots i have attached

Comment: Please, try to add a [mcve] or a link to a fiddle where we can reproduce and debug your code. Also, why `margin-left: -33.3%` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen

Comment: I am uploading to live server, so you can check

Comment: http://ifislam.com/learnuxui/build/developing/article-video.html here is the link, please check and see, the section below video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this. Hope this helps. 
There is two way to achieve this,

1. negative-margin and VW-width
2. content in a fixed with container but let :before :after to achieve the fullwidth effect. ( The Blue One )

```css
/*Container style is for illustration purpose only */

.container {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 400px;  margin-bottom: 100px;
}


/*Can achive using vw css unit*/
.row-full {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}

/*<!--- 2nd way --> */

.content_box {
    padding: 54px 0 21px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #88bae1;
    margin-bottom: 145px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
 .content_box:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: -3000px;
    right: -3000px;
    background-color: #88bae1;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="row" style="height:100px; background: #fff;"> this is ok</div>
    <div class="row row-full" style="height:100px; background: #f00;">
        this should take 100% width
    </div>
</div>


<!--- 2nd way --> 


<div class="content_box">
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Solution of your problem

```
.joinUs:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: -3000px;
    right: -3000px;
    background-color: #ebf0f8;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

and `body{overflow-x: hidden;}`

Comment: no bro, lemme live my website, so u can check it

Comment: Its Okay, But If u can reproduce your problem in the stack fiddle it will be good to debug it.

Comment: i was trying to make stack fiddl nbut it doesnt support bootstrap styles etc tct, so it's not good, that's why i am uploading project to live

Comment: http://ifislam.com/learnuxui/build/developing/article-video.html here is the link, please check and see, the section below video

Comment: add the Css what i am updating in my answer

Comment: okay brother.....

Comment: Updated.. Check Now

Comment: @Kevin is using such a large amount of margins a good practice ?

Comment: Definitely not, but lets consider this CSS as a hack for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

after few hit and trial I found the solution:

```
.joinUs {
    width: calc(100vw - 50px);
    margin-left: -27%;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

the problem with `margin-left: -33.333333%;` is that the percentage is based on the width of the **container** which in this case is your `col-md-8`, not the viewport. Also the child element `row` stretches the width by `30px` because of `margin-left: -15px; and margin-right: -15px;` which could result in horizontal scrollbar on page. To avoid the scrollbar I added `padding: 20px 15px;` to compansate the **negative** margins by `row`.

Going through your website I found out that you are overriding Bootstrap's original classes. Never do that!

Instead **Always create your own classes**